# How can I unbind Ctrl - O from Text widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, keyboard-events, key-bindings

In Text widget <kbd>Ctrl + O</kbd> appears to be adding a new line to the text area. I have below code that binds a method to <kbd>Ctrl + O</kbd> but It still adds a newline:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

txt = tk.Text(root)
txt.bind('<Control-o>', lambda event: print("o"))
txt.bind('<Control-O>', lambda event: print("O"))

txt.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

How can I prevent <kbd>Ctrl + O</kbd> adding a newline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22910425/7032856) and [this](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/text.htm#M162) *returning the literal string "break"* prevents this from happening as in ending callback function with `return "break"`. Like:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def ctrl_o(event):
    print("o")
    return "break"

txt = tk.Text(root)
txt.bind('<Control-o>', ctrl_o)
txt.bind('<Control-O>', ctrl_o)

txt.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

With `lambda` however I was unable to `return "break"`.

Comment: You can use `lambda` like this: `txt.bind('<Control-o>', lambda event: "break")`